# How to changing my background-image css property using Mootools?

Tags: css, mootools, background-image

I am newbie。 How to changing my background-image css property using Mootools?

Answer (score 7):

Example, on page load:

```
<div id="yourElement"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('yourElement').setStyle('background-image', 'url(path/to/your/image)');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[The MooTools docs for Element.Style](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Style) should be able to answer this one for you.

Comment: I saw this code for mootools from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913173/body-background-image-change-with-fade-effect-mootools

$(document.body).setStyle('background-image','url(' + pBackground + ')');

But I don't know how to apply it...

Comment: Maybe the old docs showed an example but the latest docs do not show an example of setting background-image

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEvents({
  // fire when the DOM is loaded
  domready: function(){
    // path to the image
    var pathToBackgroundImage = '/path/to/the/image.jpg';
    // set the background-image
    $(document.body).setStyle('background-image','url(' + pathToBackgroundImage + ')');
  }
});
```

You need to take a significantly different approach if you decide you'd like to fade-in the image.

Comment: Thanks. Any demo for fade-in effect for background image? 

I saw this in http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/barackslideshow/Demo/ 

Is it possible to make it for changing background image?

Comment: It's not as easy. There's no was of strictly morphing the background image of the document. You need to create a faux-background container (a absolutely positioned div, underneath the rest of the body contents) and apply scripts on this element not the Body itself. I've never seen this being done properly before.