# How to remove image background using mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

How to remove image background using mootools. I am not sure its possible using mootools. 
Example : One of my image carries red back ground, i would like to remove its background programatically using Mootools by a button click. Any idea will be greatly appreciable.

Comment: Why is this tagged jquery.....?

Comment: ' and I tagged this question with jQuery 'cause.... '

Comment: $('#element').css({backgroundImage: 'none'}); ...using jQ

Comment: i don't have any idea how to do this. hope any spark from jquery genius.

Comment: jQuery is not Mootools.  And vice versa.  Which do you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to changing my background-image css property using Mootools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742659/how-to-changing-my-background-image-css-property-using-mootools)

Comment: close-voted as @stecb did. p.s. the title of the other post is sooooo eurospeak it's damn offensive :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.id('your-div-id').setStyle('background-color', 'transparent');

document.getElement('.div-by-class').setStyle(...);
```